# How to output string with html tags (as it is)

Tags: javascript, html

I use `<xmp>` to output the string，it showed tags well but I found the font has been changed.
Here is the code.

```js
var string ="<xmp>" + "<label style=\"color:red;\">works well but font is strange</label>" + "</xmp>"
var font = "font is same";
$('#code').html(string);
$('#font').html(font);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>code:</label><label id="code"></label>
<label>font:</label><label id="font"></label>
```

How can I resolve it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to use `.text` instead:

```js
var string ="<xmp>" + "<label style=\"color:red;\">works well but font is strange</label>" + "</xmp>"
$('#code').text(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>code:</label><label id="code"></label>
<label>font:</label><label id="font"></label>
```